# Getting Error None of the configured nodes are available:in elastic search

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch

I setup an elastic search in amazon EC2 instance , and it was setup successfully but when i am trying to hit it from local its giving this error

org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{6-rFvlYhRfWbgRGieZQB1Q}{pvt ip}{pvt ip:9300}]

and the code in property file is configured like this

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=<pvt-ip>:9300
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true

api.elasticsearch.uri = http://<public-ip>:9200/
api.elasticsearch.search = /_search
```

when i checked with public ip/_nodes then the nodes ip is showing as pvt ip . Not able to find what is the issue

Pom dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I suppose `pvt ip` means private ip and `public ip` public ip and you have IP addresses in that configuration?

Accessing the public ip with the REST protocol seems to work as you wrote. From where do you want to connect when you are _trying to hit from local_, where is your application running? And which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Yes you are correct about pvt ip and public ip and about the elastic search version i have updated the pom in question and elastic search version is 1.7.2",   and i am currently running application in my local server in my pc and later i will deploy it to a beanstalk

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I am very new to elastic search but i know little aws so i think as the node is the private ip it will not be able to communicate to the internet and hence it is failing

Comment: your pom does not show which versions of Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch you use. ES 1.7.2 is from September 14, 2015 and is way beyond any support. There never was a version of Spring Data Elasticsearch supporting ES 1.7. Spring Data Elasticsearch 1.3.6 from September 2016 targeted ES 1.5.2 and Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.0.0 from April 2016 targeted ES 2.2.0. Any reason why you are using such an outdated unsupported version? Besides that, you tagged your question with _elasticsearch-5_

Comment: I am fairly new to elastic search so i was not looking for any kind of version , i will try to update the version and check it once

Comment: I have upgraded to elastic search on 6.3.2 but still it is not working and i am pretty sure the issue is because the node is configured to run on private ip

Comment: As above, the same question: From where do you want to connect when you are trying to hit from local, where is your application running?